# Create a new user and install windows service using that user

Tags: wix, windows-installer, wix3.5

I am working on a new Wix installer.

1. What I am trying to do is copy the .exe to a directory.
2. Create a new user.
3. Install the windows service using that new user.

   ```
   <!-- Create User -->
   <util:User Id="UpdateUserLogonAsService" UpdateIfExists="yes" CreateUser="yes" Name="ServiceUser" PasswordNeverExpires="yes" Password="secret" />

   <ServiceInstall Id="ServiceInstaller"
                                      Type="ownProcess"
                                      Vital="yes"
                                      Name="Windows:service"
                                      DisplayName="Windows service install"
                                      Description="test"
                                      Start="auto"
                                      Account="ServiceUser"
                                      Password="secret"
                                      ErrorControl="ignore"
                                      Interactive="no" />
   <ServiceControl Id="StartService"
                   Start="install"
                   Stop="both"
                   Remove="uninstall"
                   Name="Windows:service"
                   Wait="yes" />
   ```

Creating the User works,  Installing the service works as long as I use my current login and password.  But as soon as I try and use the new user I get the following error message.

> Verify that you have sufficient privileges to install system service

[image]

I have tried running the msi as administrator and it doesn't change the error still appears.  I am guessing it has something to do with my not having permissions to install a service to run under another use.  But that's a guess.

Comment: I am dealing with the same problem, and I believe it is actually that the new user is not yet created when ServiceInstall is trying to assign it as the Account. I think this because If I create an identical account beforehand (using Powershell, for instance) then use that in ServiceInstall, it uses that account to run the service without a problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to grant the user the SeServiceLogonRight right using the LogonAsService as attribute of the Util::User element.

FWIW, that error message is very generic and usually wrong because Windows Installer can't possibly know why your service failed to respond (start) correctly.  You may have other problems ( such as your service writing to a directory that your account has permissions to that the service account doesn't )  but at a minimum you have this problem.

Here's some fun.  While on that screen, go into Services.msc and manually switch the service to SYSTEM and back to the account.  You should get a prompt saying that the account has been granted the right.   Then hit  Retry on your dialog.  If the install works, that was your only problem.

This right can be seen in the group policy editor.  The install will seem to work from then on because the right is already set externally thanks to Services.msc.   Revert the VM or remove the right using group policy and the problem will come back.  Fix the installer, rebuild and retest and the right should automatically get applied by WiX during the install.

Comment: It doesn't actually appear to install the service.  The user is installed though.

Comment: Your wxs is redacted so it's hard to say.  Can you post an install log?  Have you read the log?

Comment: This is my first installer with Wix.   Install log? there is an install log! Now I have to go find that.

Comment: WiX creates Windows Installer (.MSI) databases.  MSI supports logging:  http://blogs.technet.com/b/richard_macdonald/archive/2007/04/02/how-to-interpret-windows-installer-logs.aspx

Comment: I having the same problem, install log not giving me some useful information. It seems there is no way to login the service automatically to that user.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to LogonAsService, you need to specify it's a local machine account:

```
Account=".\ServiceUser"
```

Comment: Since I used a property, I had to specify `Account=".\[SERVICEACCOUNT]"` for a local account. Without the `.\` it failed to work.